# Working out expectation of a random sample.

Tags: statistics, random, sampling

I have the problem:

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be a random sample from a population that has
>   mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$.
>
> Find $\mathbb E[(X_1-X_2)^2]$ and hence the value of $k$ such that $T
>  = k[(X_1-X_2)^2 + (X_3-X_4)^2]$ is an unbiased estimator of $σ^2$.

How would I go about this? I have no clue

Comment: Are the random variables dependent or independent?

Comment: @callculus It doesn't specify whether they're dependent or independent but I would assume the latter.

Comment: Random sample implies independence in general. Do you know what do you have to do? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @stubbornatom I honestly have no clue where to even start. I know E(X1)=E(X2) = μ but that’s the furthest I’ve been able to do

Comment: What is the definition of unbiased estimator?